# VS2008 hidden toolbox tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, toolbox

I am creating a new Silverlight project in Visual Studio 2008 Sp1. Further creating a new "My test tab" in the Toolbox and try to add some controls using "Choose toolbox items". After clicking the OK button of the "Choose toolbox items" dialog, no controls are added to the newly created tab.

When the tab loose focus, the tab get hidden. I mean when I try to add another tab with the same name as the first one, I get an error "Already there is a tab with the same name.", but the tab is not visible.

"Reset toolbox" doesn't work at this case, I`ve tried to delete the toolbox.tbd files in the App Data folder, but it doesn't work, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding controls from the "Choose toolbox items dialog"->Silverlight controls tab? Confirm this since toolbox will not show the controls if opened project does not support it. Also, try deleting all tbd files from the App Data folder and restart the Visual Studio might help.